# Access dynamic(mysql) multiple field values of selected options using jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery, name-value, dynamic-values

```
<select id="sub-category" name="scat[]" multiple="multiple" placeholder="Select SubCategories"><option val=""></option>';
```

I have used select2 jquery plugin for selecting mutiple categories. 
Now i need to access values of multi-selected options using jquery like below.
Can anyone help me.

```
tag1= $("#sub-category[0]").val();
tag2= $("#sub-category[1]").val();
tag3= $("#sub-category[2]").val();
tag4= $("#sub-category[3]").val();
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, if you find any answer to resolving your problem, accept the answer by green mark on left side of answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will log the value of every selected option

```
$(function(){
    $('#some_button').click(function(){
        $('#sub-category :selected').each(function(){
            console.log($(this).val());
        });
    });
});
```